# how can i resume a broken download in ubuntu with 404 not found error

Tags: ubuntu

i was downloading a file in Firefox in Ubuntu. but it stopped in the middle of the work. i want to resume this download because it is a large file and i don,t want to start it from scratch. i try these commands:

```
wget -c <url>
wget --continue <url>
wget "<url>"
wget <url>
wget -4 <url>
```

all of these returns this error:

> |:443... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not
>   Found 2017-08-19 15:57:39 ERROR 404: Not Found.

how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: what is the site domain of the file?

Comment: @Awais Soomro: my link is like : (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/... )

Comment: have you tried downloading it again in browser?

Comment: for the first time, it was downloading well and stopped almost at the end. because the size of file is relatively large, i didn't try to re download it. i like to resume downloading.